Colimits of underlying $n$-categories vs. $n$-uple categories
A double category is a category object in categories. There is a functor (of $1$-categories) $u : \mathrm{Cat}(1\mathrm{Cat}) \to 2\mathrm{Cat}$ from double categories to $2$-categories which is right adjoint to the inclusion $2\mathrm{Cat} \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Cat}(1\mathrm{Cat})$; informally, $u(C) \subseteq C$ contains all and only the $2$-cells of $C$ whose vertical boundaries are identities. Say we have a diagram $F : I \to \mathrm{Cat}(1\mathrm{Cat})$.
Question 1: Are there reasonable conditions on $F$ which ensure that the canonical map $m : \mathrm{colim}_I uF \to u(\mathrm{colim}_I F)$ is an equivalence of $2$-categories?
Here is a non-example. Given a category $A$ we can form:

a double category $\mathrm{Sq}(A)$ whose objects are those of $A$, whose horizontal and vertical $1$-cells are the morphisms of $A$, and whose $2$-cells are the commutative squares in $A$;
another double category $\mathrm{Sq}(A)^{\mathrm{hop}}$ by reading the horizontal $1$-cells of $\mathrm{Sq}(A)$ backwards;
and a double category $V(A)$ whose objects are those of $A$, whose vertical $1$-cells are the morphisms of $A$, and with only identity horizontal $1$-cells and $2$-cells.

There are inclusions $V(A) \hookrightarrow \mathrm{Sq}(A), \mathrm{Sq}(A)^{\mathrm{hop}}$. The $2$-category
$$
u(B) = u(\mathrm{Sq}(A) \cup_{V(A)} \mathrm{Sq}(A)^{\mathrm{hop}})
$$
is, in general, nontrivial: the $2$-cells are "hammocks" of commutative squares between zigzags of $1$-morphisms in $A$, subject to the condition that the two boundary $1$-cells of each hammock are identities. See, for example, Adjoining Adjoints by Dawson-Paré-Pronk. On the other hand, $u(\mathrm{Sq}(A)) \simeq A$, $u(\mathrm{Sq}(A)^{\mathrm{hop}}) \simeq A^\mathrm{op}$, and $u(V(A)) \simeq \mathrm{core}(A)$, where all the categories on the right-hand side of the equivalences are considered as vertically trivial double categories; in particular, the $2$-category
$$
u(\mathrm{Sq}(A)) \cup_{u(V(A))} u(\mathrm{Sq}(A)^{\mathrm{hop}}) \simeq A \cup_{\mathrm{core}(A)} A^\mathrm{op}
$$
does not have non-trivial $2$-cells. Therefore $m$ is not an equivalence.
If, however, we glue $B = \mathrm{Sq}(A) \cup_{V(A)} \mathrm{Sq}(A)^{\mathrm{hop}}$ to its vertically opposite double category $B^{\mathrm{vop}}$ along its underlying horizontal $1$-category $h(B)$ (seen as a vertically trivial double category) then we have
$$
u(B) \cup_{u(h(B))} u(B^{\mathrm{vop}}) \simeq u(B \cup_{h(B)} B^{\mathrm{vop}}),
$$
as can be seen by a generators-and-relations argument. Thus $m$ is an equivalence.
Note that $u$ affects the horizontal composition of $2$-cells: a $2$-cell in $X$ with trivial vertical boundary which is obtained by horizontally composing two $2$-cells $\alpha$ and $\beta$ might not be seen in $u(X)$ because $\alpha$ and $\beta$ fail to have a common trivial vertical boundary and thus do not exist as $2$-cells in $u(X)$. I think this is the reason why the first example fails and the second succeeds, namely that the first colimit adds new horizontal composites while the second one does not, in the sense that horizontal composition across $2$-cells in different pieces of the colimit can be transformed to vertical compositions of $2$-cells each of which is fully contained into a single piece of the colimit. This is admittedly very vague, apologies, hence why I'm asking this question.
I'm secretly interested in the following $\infty$-categorical generalization and I'm hoping that the ordinary case will at least show which direction to follow. An $n$-uple Segal space is an $n$-simplicial space $X : \mathbb{\Delta}^{n, \mathrm{op}} \to \mathrm{Spaces}$ which satisfies the Segal condition in every variable independently; iteratively, it is a category object in $(n-1)$-uple category objects in spaces. An $n$-fold Segal space is an $n$-uple simplicial space each of whose $k$-cells is appropriately globular. More precisely,

$1$-fold Segal spaces are just $1$-uple Segal spaces, and
$n$-fold Segal spaces are category objects in $(n-1)$-fold Segal spaces whose value at $0$ (the space of objects) is constant.

There is a functor $u : \mathrm{Cat}^n(\mathrm{Spaces}) \to \mathrm{Seg}^n(\mathrm{Spaces})$ which is right adjoint to the inclusion of $n$-fold Segal spaces into $n$-uple Segal spaces (see Iterated spans and classical topological field theories by Haugseng). Now let $F : I \to \mathrm{Cat}^n(\mathrm{Spaces})$ be a functor of $\infty$-categories.
Question 2: Are there reasonable conditions on $F$ which ensure that the canonical map $m : \mathrm{colim}_I uF \to u(\mathrm{colim}_I F)$ is an equivalence of $n$-fold Segal spaces?

I have heard Lyne Moser talking about this kind of thing, so you should check her papers if you have not already done so, but I cannot remember exactly what she said.

Thanks for the pointer! I cannot find anything from her papers, but it's possible that I haven't searched well enough. I might try to contact her
